# Schema Best Practice with Rapidly Changing Relationships

Tags: mysql, jpa, database-design

I currently have a MySQL database with a number of tables and join tables where each entity can be both a child and a parent of the other.

In other words they are equal relationships that can exist independently, be related, or change relationships.

I don't want to CASCADE a delete operation to everything it touches when I kill a row, I simply want the relationships erased and the row deleted. What is the best practice for this? Disable foreign key constraints? Would this leave half-empty rows in my join tables?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a cross reference table. Cascade the delete only as far as the xref but not all the way to the linked row

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for that input, I am using Spring JPA to write the SQL and I changed the CascadeType to DETACH. This deleted the entry and the join table entries, but not the associated entry in the other table. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with doing cascade on relationships in tables without their own primary key, but everywhere else leaving default check behavior.